# SDWebImage starts to load too late

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I am using the following function inside `dequeResuableCell` to update the image in the cell

```
    let imageNSURL = NSURL(string: post.imageUrl)
    let placeHolderImage = UIImage(named: "LoadingPlaceHolder")!
    postImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(imageNSURL, placeholderImage: placeHolderImage, options: [], progress: { (byteSent: Int, byteExpectedToSend: Int) in
        // Progress

        }, completed: { (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, imageCacheType: SDImageCacheType, url: NSURL!) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                // Image Download Complete
            }
    })
```

However, every time the cell is "just about to appear", I see a glimpse of the placeHolder image. It seems like the `SDWebImage` SDK only starts downloading the image close to when the cell actually appears on the screen. I was wondering if anyone else is experiencing this or knows how it could be fixed?

----Update----

In response to the comments

I thought cellForRowAtIndexPath is called way ahead of cell being actually displayed (2,3 cells?). willDisplayCell is the one that is displayed just before the cell is shown. But I guess Im wrong as what you said made sense.  I was't scrolling very fast and the file is only 55kb. Caching the image works but that is only after the image gets downloaded. What I want to achieve is that the image gets downloaded maybe 2,3 cells earlier so that it is ready in the cache for the cell to be loaded.

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called just before  the cell is about to appear. That is the idea.

Comment: @user172902 I would think that is the intended implementation. Basically, images only for cells that 'would/will appear' will be downloaded, instead of all cell's images for performance reasons.

Comment: I think it's suppose to be like that, `sd_setImageWithURL ` is called when the cell if about to appear, not before, if you want it to appear immediately then you have to config SDWebImage to cache your image on disk, then the 2nd time it wont load again

Comment: I second that. Configuring SDWebImage to cache the image should probably solve the issue, wherein it would check if there is a cached image, then display it. Else, display a placeholder image until it downloads the actual one.

Comment: Please see my updated question in response to your comments. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is probably network latency.

Depending on the cache state of the url you are loading, `SDWebImage` will probably be downloading the image from a remote server and depending on the size and network type this could take a few moments.

You aren't trying to load the image until the cell is dequeued, this only happens moments before the cell is displayed. You probably want to look at something like [`SDWebImagePrefetcher`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/3.3/Classes/SDWebImagePrefetcher.html). This would allow you to cache the images at an earlier stage in your app lifecycle and should (in most cases) ensure the images are available locally prior to showing the cell eliminating network latency.